# Delete Item from DynamoDB not deleting

Tags: javascript, node.js, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, serverless-framework

I can't for the life of me figure out why this isn't actually deleting the Item from the DB. It returns with a success as if it actually deleted the item but it's not actually performing the delete.

I'm using the Javascript SDK in a lambda using `serverless` framework

```
import * as dynamoDbLib from "./libs/dynamodb-lib";
import { success, failure } from "./libs/response-lib";
import { isEmpty } from 'lodash';

export function main(event, context, callback) {
  const params = {
    TableName: process.env.tableName,
    // 'Key' defines the partition key and sort key of the item to be removed
    // - 'tagId': path parameter
    Key: {
      tagId: event.pathParameters.id
    }
  };

  try {
    dynamoDbLib.call("delete", params).then((error) => {
      if(!isEmpty(error)){
        console.log(error)
        callback(null, failure({ status: false, error }));
      }else{
        callback(null, success({ status: 204 }));
      }
    });
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e)
    callback(null, failure({ status: false }));
  }
}
```

The dynamodb-lib file looks like this

```
import AWS from "aws-sdk";

AWS.config.update({ region: "us-east-1" });

export function call(action, params) {
  const dynamoDb = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

  return dynamoDb[action](params).promise();
}
```

Every other call so far, `put` and `scan` (to list all) are working just fine, delete is the only one so far that's not actually doing anything

**EDIT: This is my table structure by the way**

```
Resources:
  NametagsTable:
    Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
    Properties:
      # Generate a name based on the stage
      TableName: ${self:custom.stage}-nametags
      AttributeDefinitions:
        - AttributeName: tagId
          AttributeType: S
      KeySchema:
        - AttributeName: tagId
          KeyType: HASH
      # Set the capacity based on the stage
      ProvisionedThroughput:
        ReadCapacityUnits: ${self:custom.tableThroughput}
        WriteCapacityUnits: ${self:custom.tableThroughput}
```

Here is the function in `serverless.yml`

```
delete:
    # Defines an HTTP API endpoint that calls the main function in delete.js
    # - path: url path is /tags/{id}
    # - method: DELETE request
    handler: delete.main
    events:
      - http:
          path: tags/{id}
          method: delete
          cors: true
```

Comment: Confirm that id is the name of your path parameter.

Comment: @cementblocks added the function definition to the question

Comment: I would log `event.pathParameters.id` in the function and verify the value is what you think it is.

Comment: I had logged it and in my cloud watch I saw the ID I expected to see

Comment: add `.catch(err => { console.log(err) })` to the promise chain.